# Mixed Content with cdn bootstrap http over https

Tags: css, prestashop, cdn

I'm running on prestashop 1.6 and i have the following error...

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://nnn.pt/pt/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
In my header.tpl i cannot find this :(

[image]

Comment: Templates are in theme directory.

Comment: Find the source calling the bootstrap, it is calling it in HTTP but it needs to call it in HTTPS, change it and the error will go away.

Comment: You can indicate that your problem is solved by accepting your own answer below. You should not edit your question to add "Solved: " to the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the E-goi module was calling Bootstrap through HTTP.